# Finding index of specific date in dateTimeArray

Tags: c#, winforms

In array of int[] or double[] we can use to find an index of particular value/object using indexOf. But not the case of dateTime[] arrays. How to find the index of specific date in array of dates?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DateTime[] myDates = new DateTime[10];
        int index = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {myDates[i] = new DateTime(2016, 10, i + 1);}
    }
 }
}
```

Here what i tried to find the index

```
//Find the index of October 7,2016
        DateTime dateTimeFindIndex = new DateTime(2016, 10, 7);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(dateTimeFindIndex==myDates[i])
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }

        }
```

Are there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ind = Array.IndexOf(myDates,dateTimeFindIndex);
```